# Calculate sum of two values from different connections in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

There are two tables from two connections (via SQL). Table 1 has Quantity, Date and Group variables. Table 2 has the same columns, but also 5 extra. I want to create a table, which shows sum of Quantity per same Date and Group in two tables.

I wanted to do kind of "union all" as in excel by creating extra columns in Table 1. However, do not know how it is possible to "union all" the two tables as in SQL. Now tableau offers join functions, however the expected result is not achieved.

Could you help how create a table, which shows sum of Quantity per same Date and Group in two tables?

Comment: You can do a union all in sql. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Join not union will do this but only if you define the join correctly. Tell us what you did and we might be able to say why.

Answer (score 0):

You could blend the data sources, with a relationship on Date and Group. Also, as your data source is SQL, you could do the join on the SQL layer.